# Access localhost with self signed certificate over https using Ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, ssl, localhost

I am working on a NodeJS application which runs a server on  `https://localhost:port` and uses a self signed certificate (as no vendor provides a certificate for localhost). I am using **AJAX** call from my website to hit the locahost and send data to the NodeJs app. My calls are getting blocked due to INSECURE_CONTENT which is expected. I want to know if we have any workarounds for this?

Comment: I have tried iframe redirect. It does not work and throws `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: A more feasible way would be to have the local app connect to your online app and listen for data. Using websockets for e.g.

Answer (score 5):

(**see update below**)

Workaround is to enable it on browser level. This should allow AJAX calls also.

### For Chrome

1. Go to this url in chrome ([chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost](http://chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost))
2. [image]
3. Hit enable.
4. Then you have to relaunch your chrome browser so changes may affect.

### For Firefox

1. Go to your localhost in firefox. It should show you warning.
2. Click Advanced
3. Click Add Exception...
4. New popup window will appear, click Get Certificate
5. Verify that checkbox says 'Permanently store this exception'
6. Click 'Confirm Security Exception'. Refer Image below.

   - [image]
   - [image]

### UPDATE:

As per op's comment, updated answer is below:

([Reply to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949507/access-localhost-with-self-signed-certificate-over-https-using-ajax/46116098?noredirect=1#comment79196701_46116098)) For this simple hack is to have a `proxy` route in your node app. Create route like `http://localhost/proxy?yourwebsites_api/getData`. In node server proxy route will get `GET` parameter from your url and hit your website server. And will return same response back. Like you do in `c#` with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or in `PHP` with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: I would never recommend this option to the customers. It requires manual steps and customers are totally non technical. Why would they use my product if they have to do all these stuff. Also, they can be more curious about the security issues.

Comment: From a developer perspective I answered this question. If you're using for clients, and it's localhost then there's no point using `https`. Or you can create window based app using electron. (https://electron.atom.io/)

Comment: I have created window based app using nwjs and my website needs to pass data to the app. For this, I am creating a local node server on the client's machine. As my website runs on https, browser does not allow to make any ajax calls to http and for https I need certificate which cannot be issued for the localhost. Self signed certificate does not help as browser needs to add an exception which is a manual process. Now using image to send data to node nd responding a 1x1 img from the local node server incase of a successful communication which is working perfectly on http from a https website.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about image. But for your situation I have updated an answer.

Comment: This answer is completely disregarding the fact that this app is part of an installation procedure and is windows specific as well.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer have you read the comments and updated answer?

Answer (score 3):

Add an entry for `local.host 127.0.0.1` to your local hosts file to point the local.host domain to 127.0.0.1 ( on that machine only )
You can then create a self signed certificate for `local.host`, make sure to use this with your nodejs app, **and** and add it to the root certificate store on your machine, this will make the browser recognize the certificate.
You need the `local.host` entry because you need a well formated domain name for your self signed certificate.

You can create a self signed certificate like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 1000 -subj '/C=US/ST=CA/L=MV/CN=local.host'  -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout local.host.key -out local.host.crt
```

On osx the hosts file is located on `/etc/hosts` on windows it's at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Here is how you can add your certificate to the root certificate store:

OSX:
https://pubs.vmware.com/flex-1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.horizon.flex.admin.doc%2FGUID-9201A917-D476-40EF-B1F4-BBF14AB83D94.html

Windows:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows

Update:

Op pointed out by OP the  app would be installed on a consumer desktop.

You could potentially generate a certificate for a myapp.mydomain.com, and point  that to 127.0.0.1 after you require the certificate. 
This does not require you to add a certificate to to the root store. However, this will still require you to ship the private key with the app, which compromises the certificate for all users, it will also be painful to update the certificate. 
**This is not a good solution.**

You can generate a unique certificate during installation and install it in the root store. 
This also compromises the certificate, but only to the specific user. This reduces the attack vector, as the certificate it self is only supposed to protect the user, this is actually also how charlesproxy works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a ui based app installed by downloading a setup that will be exe for windows and pkg for mac. We are not sure if the app is installed as root, so updating hosts file is not really an option. :(

Comment: hmm, still it needs lots of scripts to be run which should not be done from a 3rd party app. I figured out a different solution. Creating an image object in Javascript and using pixel tracking to send the data to the app which does shows warning in the browser but http request works from a https page.

Comment: The user has already installed your app. There is nor reason you couldn't run any of those scripts. I guess a cleaner solution would be to run webkit your self instead of running it trough the browser. ( trough node-webkit or elector , like slack does ). Not sure how pixel tracking solves your issue here.

Comment: I am using node-webkit. I think you didn't get the question. I have a separate web application which is supposed to send the data from browser to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The very easiest way to do this is to get an ngrok account. 
Ngrok uses wildcardcerts so you can run your server on your local machine but your urls start https://*mycompany*.ngrok.io

In addition to being more like a real server (urls can ignore the port) the ngrok control panel lets your replay messages (e.g. a form post breaks something server side; fix your server side code and re-play from the ngrok control panel so you don't have to fill in the form again)

Ngrok is also great if you want to be able to share your work in progress. The tunnels that ngrok creates are open to the public (unless you password protect them)

It's $60 per year for your own domain. 
Free if you want to use random domains like https://ba615d46.ngrok.io

Comment: Routing everything trough an external third party service is hardly going to increase security.

Comment: You wouldn't use this for production data. It's a dev tool. FWIW however ngrok does sell their service as being secure

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't provide any code. Is it an Express application? If so, the this may help.

```js
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.enable('trust proxy')

app.use((request, response, next) => {
  if (this.request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
    return response.redirect(`https://${request.headers.host}${request.url}`)
  }
  return next()
})

const server = app.listen(process.env.port || 5000, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:' + server.address().port)
})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getMessage();
</script>
```